# XCOPY not copying directories

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, xcopy

I am trying to copy one directory to another directory. It seems I can copy a file but directories won't copy.

Running this at cmd:

```
XCOPY C:\Drivers C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop
```

Gives

```
0 File(s) copied
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please, see help for XCOPY

```
 /S           Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones.
 /E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
```

Comment: Glad to help, please, mark this as answer if it helped you.

Comment: unless a folder contains something other than a folder, it is considered empty, even if that sub folder contains files

Answer (score 1):

To copy C:\FolderA, including its empty folders and files, to C:\FolderB

```
xcopy /e /i "C:\FolderA" "C:\FolderB\FolderA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to copy all the files and folders in `C:\Drivers` to `C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop`:

```
XCOPY /S /E C:\Drivers\*.* C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop
```

Like the other person said

```
/S           Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones.
/E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
```

You can also look for other parameters of `xcopy` from [here](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm).

Comment: Wouldn't you only need `/S` OR `/E`, not both?